# Can you edit the headers of an incoming request in Apache httpd v2.4.6?

Tags: apache

Apache documentation states ProxyPreserveHost:

> When enabled, this option will pass the Host: line from the incoming request to the proxied host

Otherwise:

> the hostname specified in the ProxyPass line (is used)

In the Apache conf, is there any way to set a custom Host to one that isn't either of those?
e.g. `ProxySetHost customHostName`

//EDIT
In nginx, it is possible to use this annotation:

> **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-name**:
>   Allows to set proxy_ssl_name. This allows overriding the server name used to verify the certificate of the proxied HTTPS server. This value is also passed through SNI when a connection is established to the proxied HTTPS server.

Is there anything similar to this in Apache httpd?

Comment: `ProxyPreserveHost` means it will keep the same Apache httpd host in the browser and fetch data from the backend server without changing HostName in the browser. is there any specific requirement to change hostname in URL?

Comment: @Pandurang I want to reverse proxy requests to a specific Server Block in nginx. That requires me to set the Host in the request to the corresponding service. I can't set it in the ProxyPass line because it must be set to the ip as I am unable to make changes to the DNS.

Comment: If you are using Apache httpd as frontend  and Nginx as reverse proxy then only Apache HostName will visible to the user or in the browser.

Comment: @Pandurang I'm using Apache httpd as a reverse proxy for nginx. Not sure if you meant the same thing. Are you saying setting the Host to something else (minus ProxyPass & ProxyPreserveHost) just isn't possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found my own answer. To be more clear I was looking for a way to modify the host sent through the SNI extension which occurs before the http headers are sent between my apache frontend and the nginx backend. The SNI seemed to be set when using SSLProxyPreserveHost, which is evident if you look at the module's source code (not in the documentation however).

I dug through the proxy module source code for httpd on github and it looks like there are only 3 cases where the host is changed for SNI:

(proxy_util.c - https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/proxy/proxy_util.c)

Case 1: (Explained by comment block)

```
        /*
         * In the case of ProxyPreserveHost on use the hostname of
         * the request if present otherwise use the one from the
         * backend request URI.
         */
        dconf = ap_get_module_config(r->per_dir_config, &proxy_module);
        if (dconf->preserve_host) {
            ssl_hostname = r->hostname;
        }
```

Case 2: Think it only happens if forward proxy is set up (i'm using reverse proxy).

```
        else if (conn->forward
                 && ((forward_info *)(conn->forward))->use_http_connect) {
            ssl_hostname = ((forward_info *)conn->forward)->target_host;
        }
```

Case 3: Otherwise set to the host specified in the ProxyPass line.

```
        else {
            ssl_hostname = conn->hostname;
        }
```

I added a comment to one of the bug reports for httpd, linking if anyone is interested in following it: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64422